# React - How to apply CSS styles to iframe content

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, iframe

On a React app, how could I apply CSS styles to the src content that is been loaded by iframe?

I have an app loading external content, but the styles are really dated and I'd like to overwrite it.

Example Bellow: (Please note I replaced the `src` content of the `<iframe/>`, with some dummy data, however, the problem is still the same.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class Frame extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    document
      .querySelector("iframe")
      .contentWindow.document.querySelector("h1#firstHeading").style.color =
      "red";
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <iframe
        title="How Can I overwrite the styles from the src content?"
        src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbie_Hancock"
        width="90%"
        height="500px"
        scrolling="no"
      />
    );
  }
}


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Frame />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here's a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6v36vj1vx3) illustrating my problem.

In the sandbox example, I'd like to change the `h1#firstHeading` color to `red`.

Answer (score 7):

Normally, you'd do this with JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.document.querySelector("h1#firstHeading").style.color = "red";
```

However, this isn't allowed for cross-origin iframes.

> Error: Blocked a frame with origin "..." from accessing a cross-origin frame.

Comment: Would you please show me how to based on my sandbox code?

Comment: This solution directly sets the color on the control. The question was how to apply CSS styles to the Iframe

Answer (score -2):

This question is not React specific, and is answered at [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe).

Overall, although there may be some hacks and workarounds, there isn't a reliable solution unless you have control over the website you are embedding or the website has relaxed CORS settings.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I was hoping to learn how I would implement that having it wired with a React App.

Comment: This question IS or at least can be React specific. The answer in the link uses hardcoded styles or a separate link to a CSS file which may not be the case in a React application.

Comment: using Iframe within react is not straight forward... so this question is react specific

Comment: in normal HTML you can do
`<iframe style="height: calc(100vh - 50px)" src=...>`
in  react you need to wrap style with {{ as so...
`<iframe style={{height: 'calc(100vh - 50px)'}} src=...>`